# How can I install old software collections packages on CentOS 6?

Tags: centos, package-management, scl

I have a Dockerfile for building on Centos 6 with GCC 5.3 that looks like this:

```
FROM centos:6
RUN yum -y update && yum -y install centos-release-scl
RUN yum -y update && yum -y install devtoolset-4-gcc-c++
RUN scl enable devtoolset-4 ./build.sh  #Build with gcc 5
```

Unfortunately devtoolset-4 is [no longer supported](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/devtoolset-4/) in centos-release-scl. It's not hard to find mirrors which still seem to have the file; e.g.

http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/sclo/x86_64/rh/devtoolset-4/devtoolset-4-gcc-c++-5.3.1-6.1.el6.x86_64.rpm

But I'm not sure how to install from this (or from a local download of it). Any help would be much appreciated.

NB. I know it's not ideal to use unsupported packages, but the the only alternative i can find is to build GCC from scratch, which takes so long that my docker build times out in CI.

Answer (score 0):

Devtoolsets below version 6 have moved. To enable them:

```
yum -y install centos-release-scl
yum-config-manager --enable centos-sclo-rh-testing
```